# Horizontall scrolling div shadow does not cover the child background

Tags: css, scroll, background, shadow

I have horizontal scrolling container, that contains child´s with background-color. I tried to add shadow but its not working for ovarlay child background. Z-index didn't help me in this case.

There is any way to achieve this?

```css
.container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,white,white),linear-gradient(to right,white,white), linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0.25),rgba(255,255,255,0)), linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,0,0,0.25),rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-position: left center,right center,left center,right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 20px 100%,20px 100%,20px 100%,20px 100%;
    background-attachment: local,local,scroll,scroll;
}

.tag {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 var(--theme-padding-sm);
    border-radius: var(--theme-radius); 
    justify-content: center;
    width: var(--theme-width-md);;
    height: var(--theme-height-md);
    background: var(--topic-tag-background);
    border: 2px solid transparent;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <a>
  <div class="tag-container">
   <div class="tag">
    <span>BO</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, you can work around to achieve your desired result. But if you create an `::after` pseudoselector to place your shadow (in this case I've included a gradient because is more flexible than an image) you can manage it better.

```css
.container  {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
}

.container::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4682247899159664) 100%);
}

.container-overflow {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.tag-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

.tag {
    padding: 0 var(--theme-padding-sm);
    border-radius: var(--theme-radius); 
    justify-content: center;
    width: var(--theme-width-md);;
    height: var(--theme-height-md);
    background: var(--topic-tag-background);
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-overflow">
        <div class="tag-container">
            <a href="" class="tag">
                <span>BO</span>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="tag">
                <span>BO</span>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="tag">
                <span>BO</span>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="tag">
                <span>BO</span>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="tag">
                <span>BO</span>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="tag">
                <span>BO</span>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="tag">
                <span>BO</span>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="tag">
                <span>BO</span>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="tag">
                <span>BO</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is definitely an option, but which this I need javascript too, to hide shadow when scroll is at the end. I want try some CSS only solution.

Comment: I have to say that you always will need javascript if you want to handle scroll events. There is no way to detect when a `div` reaches the end or the edge of another with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to see this implementation [for css only] from 'https://codepen.io/matthewbeta/pen/OJmmmr'
Or original from your code
```

```css
.container {
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto;

   background-image: 

   /* Shadows */ 
   linear-gradient(to right, white, white),
   linear-gradient(to right, white, white),
  
   /* Shadow covers */ 
   linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,.25), rgba(255,255,255,0)),
   linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,.25), rgba(255,255,255,0));   

   background-position: left center, right center, left center, right center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-color: white;
   background-size: 20px 100%, 20px 100%, 10px 100%, 10px 100%;

   /* Opera doesn't support this in the shorthand */
   background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
}


span {
    width : 75px;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #bebebe
}
```

```html
 
  
   <div class="container">
   <ul>
    <span>BO</span>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>D</span>
    <span>O</span>
    <span>G</span>
    <span>P</span>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>U</span>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <span>Ipsum</span>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: my bad missed something, you can add <a href > tag before the word in the <code>span</code> hope this answer the question.thank you